# Macbook pro trackpad works but not detected in system preferences

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, preferences

My macbook pro's trackpad is working normally, but when I check up the system preferences > Trackpad, I find that NO trackpad is found!

I use macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7,
and this is the mac I use
https://support.apple.com/kb/SP747?locale=en_US

And I have the same problem in safe mode.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question and added the version of macOS you are running and the exact model of Mac this is.

Comment: Yes.  Please update with version and model info as @SteveChambers asked.  Also, try booting in Safe mode and checking the preferences again.  Is it detected in Safe Mode?

Answer (score -1):

open up system prefs and click the 'view' drop-down options (Next to the apple logo on the upper left corner of your monitor its the third option) > go to 'customize'
and check to see if there are any disabled preferences...(such as your touchpad or whatever...)

Comment: How would the preference pane for Trackpad be disabled if the OP says he goes into that same preference pane?